# Synapse Spark - Deltalake configs for Schema evolution and write optimizations

Tags: azure-synapse

I am looking for databricks equivalent properties in Synapse spark. Please let me know if there are any or workaround for the same.

1. Using MERGE command to Insert/update the data. However, it does not support schema merge. Is there any property to enable auto merge ?
   spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled ","true") in Databricks
2. How to control number of part files or optimize writes with  delta Merge command ?
   set spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite = true;
   set spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.autoOptimize.autoCompact = true;